# Enter Text in front of chart label value (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck on a code. I need your help to insert a specific text in front of a label of a line chart. As shown by the red text in this image:

[image]

**This is the current code I have for entering the label:**

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Points(10).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Points(10).ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).DataLabels.Select
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
```

**I tried this code to enter the text but it's not working:**

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Points(10).DataLabel.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).DataLabels(10).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
    InsertAfter "Text - "
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Points(10).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Points(10).ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).DataLabels.Select
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue   
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Points(10).DataLabel.Select   
Debug.Print ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).DataLabels(10).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).DataLabels(10).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange
    .Text = "Text - " & .Text
End With
```

BTW I would recommend avoiding the use of `ActiveSheet`, `Activate`, `Select` etc. Work with objects.

Comment: I tried the code you've entered but **.Text** had an error with **Unable to get the Count Property of the DataLabels Class.** I also tried deleting it to check for the alternative but it didn't work too.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code that I tired and it works.

Comment: I copied and pasted it however it still got an error.
on the **debug.print** line.

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Unable to get the Count Property of the DataLabels class.

noted on your recommendation